# Clean removal of Acrobat Reader

Tags: macos, safari, pdf

After uninstalling of Acrobat Reader from OS X 10.8.2 Safari doesn't display pdf's. I suppose that Acrobat uninstaller didn't remove plugin from Safari.

My question is how to cleanly remove Acrobat Reader?

Comment: I suppose reformatting the disk and reinstalling everything else is too extreme a measure…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this file to disable using Adobe Reader for PDFs in Safari:

/Library/Internet Plug-ins/AdobePDFViewer.plugin

http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/troubleshoot-safari-plug-acrobat-x.html

If you used Adobe's uninstaller, then you would think it would have deleted that for you anyway.

Comment: I would delete the file rather than placing it in a separate folder as described in [this blogpost](http://ilgthegeek.livius.net/2012/05/09/os-x-how-to-disable-acrobat-as-the-safari-pdf-viewer/). By doing so (rather then deleting it), you can always return on your steps.

Comment: Don't forget to do a secure delete. Why? Well a normal delete doesn't actually delete the file - it just hides it, and gives the file system permission to overwrite it when needed.